# update location scm url for maven multi module project

Tags: maven-2, version-control, branch, release

I have a maven multi module project. If I need to branch, I use the maven-versions plugin to go through my project and update the parent version number rather easily. Is there a similar plugin to update my scm location in all of my poms?

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/index.html) and its [`release:branch`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/branch-mojo.html) mojo for that? From the [Create a branch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html) page:

> Creating a branch executes the
>   following steps:
>
> - Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
> - **Change the version in the poms if you want to change it in the branch**
>     (you will be prompted for the versions
>     to use)
> - **Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination
>     of the tag**
> - Commit the modified POMs
> - Tag the code in the SCM as a new branch with a version name (this will
>     be prompted for)
> - Bump the version in the POMs if you want to change it to a new value
>     y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be
>     prompted for)
> - Commit the modified POMs